# is it possible to obfuscate while using soma.js dependency injection?

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, obfuscation

While looking at how to make JavaScript source code more secure I came upon a lot of 'solutions'. but most people said the same thing; "It's not possible to make your source code 100% secure", "try obfuscation", "run your code server side", etc, etc. After reading a lot posts here on stackoverflow, and other sites I came to the conclusion that a combination of minifying and obfuscating would do the job (for me).

But here is the problem: we are currently using soma.js with dependency injection, and the way we set it up it does not work well with obfuscation. It's basically this:

```
var session = function(id, sessionModel){
   this._sessionmodel = sessionModel;
}
```

mapping:

```
injector.mapClass("sessionModel", project.SessionModel, true);
```

Obfuscation will then rename the sessionModel in the function to for example 'A', but the mapping that was done on SessionModel by the injector still remains 'sessionModel' and not 'A', this then basically breaks the code.

I've read this post which is about the same subject [Dependency Injection and Code Obfuscation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123874/dependency-injection-and-code-obfuscation), but it does not provide a real answer to my problem so I decided to write my own question.

Any tips/hint/suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT

It seems you can tell Yuicompressor to exclude certain identifiers by putting in  'hints' into the files like this: "identifier:nomunge, identifier2:nomunge".

```
var session = function(id, sessionModel){
"sessionModel:nomunge";
   this._sessionmodel = sessionModel;
}
```

I tested this and it works but that means you'll have to put it in yourself which is a lot of work if you have to do that for every script, especially if you have a very big project..

Gonna look into it further, and update this post if anything new pops up

EDIT 2

It's been a while, I only work 1 day a week on this =S.
As said before you can get it working by telling it which identifiers to exclude. 
For that I looked into regular expression to get the "mapped classes" programmatically, since doing it by hand is just insane.

What I basically did was instead of putting every hint in by hand, I made a identifier, for example "#nomunge"; and used a simple replaceregexp task to find it and replace it with a string containing all the identifiers. This string is build by loading the script and going through it with a tokenfilter.

```
<target name="build hints">
        <loadfile property="hints" srcFile="${temp.loc}/all.js">
            <filterchain>
                <tokenfilter delimoutput=":nomunge,">
                    <ignoreblank/>
                    <containsregex pattern="${regexp}"/>
                </tokenfilter>
            </filterchain>
        </loadfile>
    <echo message="${hints}"/>
</target>    


<replaceregexp file="${temp.loc}/all.js"
                       match="#nomunge"
                       flags = "g"
                       replace = "target:nomunge, dispatcher:nomunge, injector:nomunge,${hints}"
/>
```

This seems to do the job, for now...

Comment: The simple point is that NOTHING on the client-side is ever 100% secure, because you cannot know the user's environment. If in doubt, or if doing anything even slightly important with data, ALWAYS validate it server-side first.

Comment: Hey, I'm not trying to make my code 100% secure, I'm only trying to make it less readable with obfuscation. The problem is that it currently does not work well and i'm hoping someone else knows a solution. Thanks for the input though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm behind the soma.js framework, feel free to ask me questions on the google group, happy to help.
This might help a bit more:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/somajs/noOX2R4K58g
Romu